# creating *.o files from *.cpp files in C++ project with out linking in Visual studio

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

how is it possible to make objects (*.o) files in visual studio 2010 wiht out linking from *.cpp files in visual C++ project

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve, but you can simply compile the cpp file (as opposed to building the project) to get the obj file. Ctrl-F7 when editing the file will do the trick. The file does have to compile successfully, of course, in order to get the obj file.